# How to uninstall Visual Studio 2011 Developer Preview completely

Tags: uninstall, visual-studio

My visual studio 2011 developer is about to expire in a few days. How can I remove it completely. It has installed a lot of packages that can be seen in the Control Panel > Add or remove software.

Some of them refuse to uninstall, all in all it's a huge mess. Is their some way to completely remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to uninstall manually those components. this might influce the existing installation of previous version of visual studio. it's good if you reinstall the previous ones once you uninstall VS2011.

The steps to uninstall is described in MSDN but not quite useful.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246604(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I think you're right. I had to manually uninstall them one by one.